# How to set a dynamic path for output artifact from aws_codebuild_project in Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, continuous-integration

I am trying to set up an AWS CodeBuild project in Terraform:

```
resource "aws_codebuild_project" "example" {
  name          = "test-project"
  description   = "test_codebuild_project"
  build_timeout = "5"
  service_role  = "${aws_iam_role.example.arn}"

  artifacts {
    type      = "S3"
    location  = "${aws_s3_bucket.example.bucket}"
    name      = "example.zip"
    packaging = "ZIP"
    path      = "dev/api/${var.app_version}"
  }
```

This example works fine, but it will only ever save the build artifact `example.zip` to the folder set when `terraform apply` was run, since `${var.app_version}` doesn't change on subsequent runs of this build.

How do I achieve something that, for example, takes a version number from the `package.json` file in the repo and uses that for `${var.app_version}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should not be done from the terraform side. The AWS CodeBuild docs mention how to achieve something like this by using the buildspec, although you might be constrained by only using the env variables provided by CodeBuild to add the variation to the name.

```
version: 0.2         
phases:
  build:
    commands:
      - rspec HelloWorld_spec.rb
artifacts:
  files:
    - '**/*'
  name: myname-$CODEBUILD_SOURCE_VERSION
```

You can find the extended explanation here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html